# JavaScript Files - Not Found 404 - CodeIgniter - .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My code igniter app is giving me 404 (Not found) for all js files ($DOC_ROOT/javascript/), all images and css are working fine, javascript, images and css folders have the same permissions.

my .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset ETag
 </ifModule>

 FileETag none
 <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
 </FilesMatch>

 Options All -Indexes

 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml


 <Files *.php>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </Files>


 <Files *.css>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </Files>


 <Files *.js>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </Files>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|local_clientdata|clientdata|javascript|fckeditor|themes|install|css|files|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|info\.php|forum\/)

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [E=CI_PATH:/$1,L]
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Refine the bottom lines of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```